# LinkedList nodes containing LinkedLists

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

As part of a project I'm doing where i'm using homemade linkedLists (no generics) i need to set the nodes of one linkedList (myLL) to contain the nodes of the other linkedList (myList) while sorting them by the clients (i.e. a client has jobs 1, 2, and 3 done for him and myList contains those jobs, while myLL contains the client) Do you have any suggestions on how to contain a linkedList inside of a LinkedList node?

Comment: Can you provide relevant code? LL is just Nodes linked to each other. So you can just link last node of 1st LL to 1st node of 2nd LL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this?

```
LinkedList<LinkedList> listOfList = new LinkedList<LinkedList>();

LinkedList list1 = new LinkedList();
//Add elements to list1
LinkedList list2 = new LinkedList();
//Add elements to list2
LinkedList list3 = new LinkedList();
//Add elements to list3

listOfList.add(list1);
listOfList.add(list2);
listOfList.add(list3);
```

You can replace LinkedList with ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create two classes for the nodes. One containing the client, the other containing the job-of-client.

for example: you will make a client node class like this:

```
public class Client{
int clientNumber;
String clientName;

Client clientLink;
Job jobLink;}
```

and the job node class like this:

```
public class Job {
String jobName;
int jobNumber;

Job jobLink;}
```

you will notice that both node have a variable of the same type of the class owner and that is to link the nodes with each other.

and then you will have your linked list code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LinkedList
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    Client List;
    Client Location;
    Client PredLocation;

    void CreateList()
    {
        List = null;
        System.out.println("The List Have Been Created/Destroyed Successfully!");
    }

    void DestroyList()
    {
        List = null;
    }

    boolean EmptyList()
    {
        if ( List == null ) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    void PrintAllClients()
    {
        if (EmptyList() == true)
            System.out.println("The List is Empty!");
        else
        {
            Client P = List;
            System.out.println("Client Number"+"\t"+"Client Name"+"\t");
            while (P != null)
            {
                System.out.println(P.clientNumber+"\t\t"+P.clientName+"\t\t");
                P = P.clientLink;
            }
        }
    }

    void Search(int key)
    {
        Location = List;
        PredLocation = null;

        while (Location != null)
        {
            if (Location.clientNumber == key)
                break;
            else if (Location.clientNumber > key)
                Location = null;
            else
            {
                PredLocation = Location;
                Location = Location.clientLink;
            }
        }
    }

    void InsertClient()
    {
        if (List == null)
        {
            Client P = new Client();
            P.clientNumber = 1;
            System.out.println("Enter the Name of the First Client: ");
            P.clientName = sc.nextLine();
            List = P;
            System.out.println("The Insertion of new Client was Successfull");
        }
        else
        {
            Client P = List;
            while (P.clientLink != null)
                P = P.clientLink;
            P.clientLink = new Client();
            P.clientLink.clientNumber = P.clientNumber + 1;
            System.out.println("Enter the Client Name: ");
            P.clientLink.clientName = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("The Insertion of new Client was Successfull");
        }
    }

    void RetrieveClient(int key)
    {
        Search(key);
        if (Location == null)
            System.out.println("Client is not Found!");
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Client Number"+"\t"+"Customer Name"+"\t");
            System.out.println(Location.clientNumber+"\t\t"+Location.clientName+"\t\t");
        }
    }

    void ModifyClient(int key)
    {
        Search(key);
        if (Location == null)
            System.out.println("Client is not Found!");
        else
        {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Client Number"+"\t"+"Client Name"+"\t");
            System.out.println(Location.clientNumber+"\t\t"+Location.clientName+"\t\t");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Enter the new Name: ");
            Location.clientName = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("The Modifying of the client was Successfull");
        }
    }

    void DeleteClient(int key)
    {
        Search(key);
        if (Location == null)
            System.out.println("Client is not Found!");
        else if (Location.jobLink == null)
        {
            if (PredLocation == null)
                List = Location.clientLink;
            else
                PredLocation.clientLink = Location.clientLink;
            System.out.println("The Deletion of the Client was Successfull");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Cannot Delete a Client who has Jobs!");
    }

    void AddJob(int key)
    {
        Search(key);
        if (Location == null)
            System.out.println("Client is not Found!");
        else if (Location.jobLink == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter The First Job name:");
            String A = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter The First Job number:");
            int B = sc.nextInt();
            Job P = new Job();
            P.jobName = A;
            P.jobNumber = B;
            Location.jobLink = P;
                System.out.println("The job Addetion was Successfull");             

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Enter The Job Name");
            String A = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter The Job Number");
            int B = sc.nextInt();
            Job P = Location.jobLink;
            while (P.jobLink != null)
                P = P.jobLink;
            P.jobLink = new Job();
            P.jobLink.jobName = A;
            P.jobLink.jobNumber = B;
            System.out.println("The Job Addition was Successfull");             

        }
    }

    void PrintJob(int key)
    {
        Search(key);
        if (Location == null)
            System.out.println("Client is not Found!");
        else if (Location.jobLink == null)
            System.out.println("Client has no Jobs!");
        else
        {
            Job P = Location.jobLink;
            System.out.println("Client Number"+"\t"+"Client Name"+"\t");
            System.out.println(Location.clientNumber+"\t\t"+Location.clientName+"\t\t");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Job Name"+"\t"+"Job Number");
            while (P != null)
            {
                System.out.println(P.jobName+"\t\t"+P.jobNumber);
                P = P.jobLink;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this was helpfull